# Получить id последней вставленной строки

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть два `insert` запроса.

Как для второго запроса получить значение поля `id`, которое формируется в результате выполнения первого. Для поля установлен `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Запрос в первую таблицу:

```
$login = ($_POST['login']); 
$email = (trim($_POST['email'])); 
$password = md5(md5(trim($_POST['password']))); 


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, paroli, email) VALUES (:login, :password, :email)"; 
$sqlData = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sqlData->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sqlData->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sqlData->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sqlData->execute();
```

Запрос во вторую таблицу:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO images_ava (id) VALUES (:id)"; 
$sqlData = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sqlData->execute();
```

Comment: [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php) - оно?

Comment: вроде да, а поможете пожалуйста его вставить?

Comment: После первого `execute()` вставте `$lastId = $db->lastInsertId();`, где `$db` коннект к базе. И используете `$lastId` в другом запросе.

Comment: спасибо все работает, доавте ответом я вам там балы поставлю

Comment: иногда имеет смысл завернуть обе вставки в транзакцию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить идентификатор последней вставленной записи можно воспользоваться функцией `lastInsertId`.

В данном случае ее нужно вызвать после первого вызова `execute`:

```
$lastId = $db->lastInsertId(); // $db коннект к базе.
```

Затем можно использовать `$latsId` в последующих запросах.

[PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php)